# Convert Autoit Regex to C#

Tags: c#, regex, pcre, autoit

I cant work this out, I have been given this search expression

```
.*?(8986(.{8})8A4F03)
```

which works really quick in autoit and gives me 1 result but if I try it in c# it seems to hang. I have also tried

```
(8986(.{8})8A4F03)
```

which works really quick in both autoit and c# but gives me 2 results but I only want the first result. I have read "cheat sheets" for autoit and c# but I just don't get it.

Part of the autoit code

```
Global $SearchExression = _
    ".*?(8B0D(.{8})898D40F1FFFF6A01)" & _ ;Base_Address
    ".*?(8986(.{8})8A4F03)" & _ ;LVL_Offset
    ".*?(898E(.{8})8B5714)" & _ ;Culti_Offset
    ".*?(8996(.{8})8B4718)" & _ ;EXP_Offset
    ".*?(8986(.{8})8B4F04)" & _ ;Spirit_offset
    ".*?(898E(.{8})8B570C)" & _ ;HP_OffSet
    ".*?(8996(.{8})8B471C)" & _ ;MP_OffSet
    ".*?(8986(.{8})8B4F08)" & _ ;CHI_OffSet
    ".*?(898E(.{8})8B5710)" & _ ;MaxHP_OffSet
    ".*?(8996(.{8})8B4720)" & _ ;MaxMP_OffSet
    ".*?(8986(.{8})8A4702)" & _ ;MaxCHI_Offset
    ".*?(8B108996(.{8})8B4004)" & _ ;gold_Offset
    ".*?(6A0A8986(.{8}))" & _ ;state_Offset
    ".*?(8986(.{8})8B40048BC8)" & _ ;castid_Offset
    ".*?(A1(.{8})578B482081C1EC)" & _ ;BaseCall_Offset
    ".*?(568BF18B86(.{8})85C0)" & _ ;target_Offset
    ".*?(8B8E(.{8})3BCB740655)" & _ ;pet_Offset
    ".*?(8B8E(.{8})8B47503BC8)" & _ ;str_Offset
    ".*?(8B96(.{8})8B47543BD0)" & _ ;dex_Offset
    ".*?(8B86(.{8})8B4F5C3BC1)" & _ ;vit_Offset
    ".*?(8B8E(.{8})8B47603BC8)" & _ ;mag_Offset
    ".*?(8B96(.{8})8B47643BD0)" & _ ;reputation_Offset
    ".*?(EB5D8B8E(.{8})B801)" & _ ;class_Offset
    ".*?(8B491C33C08B91(.{8})85D2)" & _ ;jump_Offset
    ".*?(32C0C38B89(.{8})568BB0)" & _ ;charid_Offset
    ".*?(8B83(.{8})8D4C243C)" & _ ;name_Offset
    "";".*?((.{8}))" & _ ;
 Global $NameArray[26] = [ _
    "Base_Address", _
    "LVL_Offset", _
    "Culti_Offset", _
    "EXP_Offset", _
    "Spirit_Offset", _
    "HP_Offset", _
    "MP_Offset", _
    "CHI_Offset", _
    "MaxHP_Offset", _
    "MaxMP_OffSet", _
    "MaxCHI_Offset", _
    "Gold_Offset", _
    "State_Offset", _
    "CastID_Offset", _
    "BaseCall_Address", _
    "TargetID_Offset", _
    "Pet_Offset", _
    "STR_Offset", _
    "DEX_Offset", _
    "VIT_Offset", _
    "MAG_Offset", _
    "Reputation_Offset", _
    "Class_Offset", _
    "Jump_Offset", _
    "CharID_Offset", _
    "Name_Offset"]
If FileExists($File) Then
    $FileHnd = FileOpen($File, 16)
    Local $Data = FileRead($FileHnd, FileGetSize($File))
    FileClose($FileHnd)
Else
    Local $Data = ""
EndIf
If $Data <> "" Then
    Local $x = 0
    Local $check = StringRegExp($Data, $SearchExression, 3)
    If IsArray($check) Then
        Global $info[UBound($check) / 2][3]
        For $i = 1 To (UBound($check) - 1) Step 2
            MsgBox(0,"",$check[$i])
            $info[$x][0] = $NameArray[$x]
            $info[$x][1] = _RemoveZero(Reverse($check[$i]))
            $info[$x][2] = Dec(Reverse($check[$i]))
            $x += 1
        Next
```

c# code so far

```
if (File.Exists(file) == true)
        {
            FileStream inputFile = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open , FileAccess.Read,FileShare.ReadWrite);
            byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[inputFile.Length];
            inputFile.Read(byteBuffer, 0, (int) inputFile.Length);
            inputFile.Dispose();
            StringBuilder client = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < byteBuffer.Length; i++)
            {
                client.Append(byteBuffer[i].ToString("X2"));
            }
            // Clipboard.SetText(client.ToString()); //get string to paste into regexbuddy

            Regex rx = new Regex(@".*?(8986(.{8})8A4F03)"); //works perfect in autoit but hangs here
            //Regex rx = new Regex(@"(8986(.{8})8A4F03)"); // too many groups + too many matches
            //Regex rx = new Regex(@"8986(.{8})8A4F03"); //one group but too many matches

            foreach (Match mx in rx.Matches(client.ToString()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(mx);
                //Console.WriteLine(mx.Groups[1]);
            }
        }
```

I didnt make the original expressions, i dont claim to know how they work

First part of the string is

```
4D5A90000300000004000000FFFF0000B8000000000000004000000
```

Result I want is

```
6C040000
```

Comment: What are you trying to match with this regex?

Comment: I don't see a reason why this should not work in c#. Please show us a source string, what you expect as result and important: the c# code.

Comment: I'm looking for a memory address, the source string has 7 million chars so I dont want to paste here. RegexBuddy gives same results/hang so its not the code that the problem, I have 26 of these expressions. .*? always cause hang, if i remove .*? some of the expressions start returning 2 results instead of 1

Comment: I don't expect you to copy/past 7 million chars, but a small part to work with. What do you mean with "2 results instead of one"? Does it match two times or do you mean the two capturing groups you are creating ... . I think its not possible to help you without the three things I asked for.

Comment: What's the point of having the .*? prefix? Without, you get two results because there are two capture groups.

Comment: This is why it seems to hang: http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html Do you understand what the pattern matches, and why it matches the results that it does? If you are trying to narrow it down to match only one, we need to see the desired matches and the undesired matches.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `.*?` in AutoIt?  Or if you change the regex to `(?s).*?(8986(.{8})8A4F03)` (again, in AutoIt)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this C# snippet:

```
string resultString = null;
resultString = Regex.Match(text, "(?<=8986).{8}(?=8A4F03)").Value;
```